# Dynamically adding custom attributes to SAML response

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, identity

I've implemented Single Sign On with Salesforce as Identity Provider scenario using SAML.  I want to pass additional attributes via SAML response to the Service Provider. Out of the box the Connected App allows adding custom attributes based on User/Profile/System objects:

[image]

I want to add attributes from other objects.

Is it even possible? Should I implement some interface to have specific fields visible?

Comment: Is said business data tied to the specific user who is signing in? I.e. Given the current user as a starting point, how would you identify the additional data of interest.

Comment: Isn't adding a custom field on the User sufficient for your use case ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you pretty much have covered all the steps an admin can perform to configure salesforce as an Identity provider. He can update the custom attributes to be sent back as part of assertion, but is limited to available dropdown options provided by Salesforce (Mentioned in your question).

However, there is a possible way to extend the custom attribute response using code. Salesforce allows developers to extend the connected app using **`Custom Connected App Handler`**. This class needs to extend **ConnectedAppPlugin** Class to extend the Connect app behavior, as mentioned below:

> Contains methods for extending the behavior of a connected app, for
>   example, customizing how a connected app is invoked depending on the
>   protocol used. This class gives you more control over the interaction
>   between Salesforce and your connected app.

Create a class following the below sample code, to populate a map of custom attributes from your business data.

```
global class ConnectedAppPluginExample extends Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin{

    // Return a user’s permission set assignments
    global override Map<String,String> customAttributes(Id userId, Map<String,String> formulaDefinedAttributes) 
    {  
        //Query Data from your business objects
        List< ObjectName > businessOjbects = [Select [fieldNames] From ObjectName Where [certain conditions]];

        for ( ObjectName businessData :businessOjbects)
        {
            //Just a sample map populated with Unique Name and id
            formulaDefinedAttributes.put(businessData.Name,businessData.id);
        }
        return formulaDefinedAttributes;
    }
}
```

You can find more details here about the same 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm#apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin

**Update**

Out of curiosity, I tried to implement it by myself (Between two SF orgs) and was able to pass additional SAML attributes as part of response.

This is what I did -

1. Follow steps listed down in this article to implement SSO between two SF orgs 
   https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations
2. Created a sample ConnectedApp handler class and selected it on the Connected App under **Custom Connected App Handler** section:

> ```
> global class ConnectedAppPluginExample extends Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin{
>     global override Map<String,String> customAttributes(Id userId, Map<String,String> formulaDefinedAttributes) 
>     {  
>         formulaDefinedAttributes.put('test','test');
>         return formulaDefinedAttributes;
>     } 
> }
> ```

**Note: There is a catch here. For some reason this class with version >37 is not working. So update its version to 36.**

3. Installed google chrome extension to track SAML assertions.
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-chrome-panel/paijfdbeoenhembfhkhllainmocckace
4. Tested the SSO and verified the SAML response with the custom attribute. **Test** attribute was present in the SAML response.

**Update 2**

Morover if you want to use higher API version you have to override `customAttributes` method like this:

```
  global override Map<String,String> customAttributes(Id userId, Id 
  connectedAppId, Map<String,String> formulaDefinedAttributes, 
  Auth.InvocationContext context) 
      {  ...
```

With additional `connectedAppId` and `context` attributes.

```xml
<saml:Attribute Name="userId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">0057F000000dRXp 
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">sfsmarty@fsl.com
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">sfsmarty@yahoo.co.in
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="is_portal_user" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">false
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="test" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
    <saml:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">test 
    </saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

Comment: Hello @Salesforcesmarty. Thanks for your answer. I've tried that earlier but I haven't noticed any change after applying this custom plugin solution. Moreover I don't know how to add such prepared custom attributes to the SAML response. Do you know any tutorial/example, not only interface implement example, that shows whole solution from start to end?

Comment: What do you mean that you don't know how to prepare custom attributes? They are nothing but key values pairs. I don't have any detailed documented examples, but I can guide if you are facing any specific challenges.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Salesforcesmarty. There is no problem with preparing custom attributes. The real problem for me is how to pass those parametres to SAML response.

Comment: @MichałKuliński I have verified the connectedApp handler and it is able to pass the additional custom attributes back in response. As part of the POC, I am passing test parameter back to Service Provider.

Comment: OMG. It is API version issue. I've changed API Version to 36 and it works :)

Comment: Is there any other solution than rolling back to API v36? I tried a similar code for my canvas app and observed the SAML attributes vie the Firefox plugin SAML Tracer. But I don't see my custom attributes that I prepared in the Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin class.

Comment: Does this override the Connected App Handler for all connected apps?  I don't see that there's one specified, so I assume so.  Wondering what the impact would be for other connected apps if we're including unexpected information in the SAML response.

Comment: i have one question, after configure 2 org salesforce, one IDP and another SP; configure the custom Attribute inside the IDP. How SP org can retrieve this custom attribute? only in JIT? or maybe in the VF page login flow?